# Разбор ответа от similarweb api в формате json

Tags: json, api

После запроса к АПИ получаю ответ в формате json:

```
"meta": {
        "request": {
            "granularity": "Daily",
            "main_domain_only": false,
            "show_verified": true,
            "format": null,
            "domain": "sait.ru",
            "start_date": "2018-07-01",
            "end_date": "2018-07-31",
            "limit": null,
            "country": "world"
        },
        "status": "Success",
        "last_updated": "2018-07-31"
    },
    "visits": [
        {
            "date": "2018-07-01",
            "visits": 211.6172665827583
        }
```

Как понимать количество визитов? 
Что значит точка в значении `visits: 211.6172665827583`? 
Сколько же все таки посещений? 211?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ. Число с точкой это результат машинного обучения. Количество посещений в данном ответе будет равняться 211. Нужно использовать int (visits);